# preprocessor define with #pragma directive

Tags: c++

I would like to do a `#define` which contains a `#pragma` directive but I got the following error.
Any idea?

```
#define FunctionPar_Begin  typedef struct fpar { #pragma pack(4)

error C2121: '#': invalid character: possibly the result of a macro expansion
```

Comment: You should be able to use [`_Pragma("pack(4)")`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl).

Answer (score 1):

The one you probably want:

```cpp
#define FunctionPar_Begin  typedef struct fpar { _Pragma("pack(4)")
```

MSVC also allows for:

```cpp
#define FunctionPar_Begin  typedef struct fpar { __pragma(pack(4))
```

Clang/gcc also allow:

```cpp
#define FunctionPar_Begin  typedef struct fpar { __attribute__((packed, aligned(4)))
```